# How can I add inline CSS for each image?

Tags: css, filters, images

Is there a filter or hook that I can use for uploaded media?

I need to use it for custom CSS properties based on the media's description. It will be like:

```
<img src="image_url" style="width:  60%;" />
```

or

```
<img src="image_url" style="width:  80%;" />
```

Media description screenshot:

[image: Edit Media screenshot]

Comment: Have you checked code of plugins that do similar things, e.h. shadow-/lightbox plugins?

Comment: Are these images post images, or something else? Are you wanting to define the inline CSS manually, or automatically?

Comment: _Have you checked code of plugins that do similar things, e.h. shadow-/lightbox plugins? – Raphael yesterday_ — No, I'm not sure they are doing the same thing.

Comment: _Are these images post images, or something else?_ — Yes, these images post images.

Comment: _Are you wanting to define the inline CSS manually, or automatically?_ — Automatically, inline CSS based on image Description content.

Comment: What's your endgoal - your _real_ target? You're so far only talking about what you want to achieve and so far it's off topic. Why don't you edit your post and tell us your situation and what you need.

Comment: Please add some clarity to your question is it is currently difficult to understand what you are looking for and how you want to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

After inserting the image, click it again and click the small edit window. You can then add inline CSS using the Advanced Settings already built into WordPress.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just use jQuery?

```
$(selector).css('width','60%')
```

Comment: I don't think so. Width is different for each image. For example Media Description is 80% so html must be _<img src="image_url" style="width: 80%;" />_

Comment: the way i will do such kind of issue is that i will get description width and set the image width from description width using javascript. Why cant u try that?